# required attribute does not work for button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

required attribute does not work for button. How to fix it?

```
<form onSubmit={this.addItem}
<input   required  type="text"  value={this.state.Description}  onChange={this.handleInput}/>
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        {this.state.activeButton ? <button type="submit" onClick={() => 
               this.appendElement(this.state.Name)}>Add</button> : <button type="submit" disabled  
               onClick={() => this.appendElement(this.state.Name)}>wait...</button>}
    </div>
<form/>
```

Comment: what is your objective? what should the button do?

Comment: when an empty input is to be activated required

Comment: Please publish a working current solution using a pen or fiddle.

Comment: I was editing the question

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is it that the onSubmit function does not get called?

Answer (score 0):

There is no attribute required for buttons:

See list of supported attributes here: 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp

Comment: I'm using bytton type = "submit" and it doesn't work either

Comment: i do not really comnpletelly understand your code because reactJs is not my field but you have put also a disabled attribute to your button which prevent it from clicking.

Comment: this is a piece of code, disabled when no response from the server